# Numbers in a folder name returns error in os makedirs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iam trying to create a directory and when i put numbers before the name of the folder i get error else it creates the directory. Does it not allow to have numbers in the name?

```
os.makedirs(self.path+'\02xyz_xz')
```

Comment: The problem is the `\0`, not the numbers. Did you mean to escape the backslash? (in which case, replace it with `\\0`)

Comment: so 0 doesnt work?

Comment: `\0` is not character-backslash followed by character-zero: it's the escape sequence for the NUL character (ASCII code 0, the C-style string terminator). You can't have that in a path, so it throws an error.

Comment: Use a proper, cross-platform, tested way to generate the path (`os.path.join` or the newer `pathlib` module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because of the `\` which tries to escape the 0. You either need a double backslash or a forwardslash

```
 os.makedirs(self.path+'/02xyz_xz')
```

Or as suggested by DeepSpace in the comments even better to create a proper Cross-Platform `Path` object

```
from pathlib import Path
(Path(self.path)/'02xyz_xz')).mkdir()
```

Comment: @USer12345 `to_csv` accepts `Path` objects for the file path parameter so you can create one in the same way as done in the (edited) answer above